# VK API. Python. Как создать индивидуальную переменную для каждого пользователя с помощью словаря?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Я познакомился с основами Python. Решив применить знания на практике, я начал постепенно создавать простого бота для ВК с использованием VK API. Попрошу без нравоучений в роде "тебе не стоит пока сюда лезть, занимайся основами" или "сначала изучи все о API, потом что-то делай".

К сути дела: Я хочу сделать одну единственную переменную для каждого пользователя - количество поинтов. На просторах интернета предлагают использовать базы данных, но не хочу с ними связываться из-за одной переменной. Я читал, что это возможно сделать с помощью словаря (ключ, значение). Хотелось бы, чтобы словарь был вида {ID: points}. Звучит достаточно просто. Как такового примера я не нашел ни тут, ни в YouTube.

Прочитал на этом форуме предложение использовать dict.get, я попытался, но этот метод напрочь отказывается записывать ID пользователя в качестве ключа. Когда я попробовал в консоли узнать тип: print(type(points)), выдало ошибку "NameError: name 'points' is not defined". Если таким образом попытаться узнать тип любой переменной, например x, выдаст такую же ошибку. Несколько часов я лазил в интернете на различных форумах, и не нашел ответа.

При запуске кода, я пишу боту команду "/point" и консоль выводит ошибку "KeyError: (мой ID в вк)". То есть строка points.get(from_id, 0) не записывает ID пользователя в словарь и следующая строка его, соответственно, не находит.

Господа айтишники, как всё-таки достичь цели? Подчеркну ещё раз, я не вижу смысла заморачиваться с MySQL и прочими базами ради одной переменной. Создаю я этого бота больше для практики, поковыряться, ради интереса. Попрошу не критиковать.

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
import random

session = vk_api.VkApi(token = 'не дам')
vk = session.get_api()
VkBotLongPoll = VkBotLongPoll(session, group_id=не дам)

def write_message(sender, message):
    session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': sender, 'message': message, 'random_id': get_random_id()})

def get_name(from_id):
    sender_info = vk.users.get(user_ids = from_id)[0]
    full_name = sender_info.get('first_name') + ' ' + sender_info['last_name']
    return full_name

points = {}

for event in VkBotLongPoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat and event.message.get('text') !='':
        msg = event.message.get('text').lower()
        sender = event.chat_id
        from_id = event.message.get('from_id')
        name = get_name(from_id)
        if msg == '/point':
            x = random.randint(1, 10)
            points.get(from_id, 0)
            points[from_id] += x
            write_message(sender, name + ', ' + f'you have earned {x} points')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Когда я попробовал в консоли узнать тип: print(type(points)), выдало ошибку "NameError: name 'points' is not defined".

Подозреваю, что функция type() вызывалась в Python Console в IDE, соответственно, в консоли переменные были не инициализированы , это и приводило к исключению. Если вызвать print(type(points)) в теле кода, либо же в режиме дебаггера - она должна вернуть <class 'dict'> , т.к в коде переменная points инициализирована как пустой словарь.

> строка points.get(from_id, 0) не записывает ID пользователя в словарь и следующая строка его, соответственно, не находит.

Метод словаря get() не перезаписывает значение в существующем словаре, а лишь только возвращает значение по переданному ключу в качестве аргумента.

Таким образом строка `points[from_id] += x` вызовет эксепшн KeyError (если бы она была с = , вместо += - тогда бы создала новый ключ с id from_id)

В данном случае, не совсем понятна структура словаря. Зачем делать ключ fromId в словаре points?  Если уж это должна быть импровизированная БД ) Скорее, здесь будет смысл считать переменную points как название таблицы (словаря с таблицей), а внутри хранить значения в виде ключ (id юзера) и значение (кол-во очков юзера).

Таким образом:

```
points = {}

points[999] = 1

print(points[999])
```

Я присвоил юзеру с id 999 значение 1.

Вы же , сначала берете несуществующее значение (думая что оно туда запишется), далее  `points.get(from_id, 0)` из словаря, при этом еще используя += делаете это: `points[from_id] += x`
(то ли присвоить, то ли хотите инкрементировать значение по несуществующему ключу - не понял).

> Попрошу без нравоучений в роде "тебе не стоит пока сюда лезть, занимайся основами"

Так что здесь сложно без этого, вам действительно стоит сначала разобраться с основами, и тогда вам будет проще. Удачи в начинаниях! :)